# Handling Facebook events

Tags: facebook

I would like to be able to trigger events in a Facebook account. For example, when a user inserts a post on my wall, I would like to save the post in my database. Is there a library that permits it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You're looking for [realtime updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/)